# Caching problems reading a URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone app where I read a bus timetable stored at a URL. The timetable changes frequently, so I want to read it afresh every time, not take a copy from cache. This is the code that I'm using:

```
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:timetable_URL]];
   NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

However, this seems to read a cached copy, so when the timetable changes on the server, it takes a while for the app to pick it up. Can anyone tell me how to force the data to be read from the server? Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the cache policy when creating your NSURLRequest

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:timetable_URL]
                          cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                        timeoutInterval:30.0];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly! I'd been trying to figure this out on-and-off for months, but somehow didn't find the right page in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cachePolicy` property on NSURLRequest specifying `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/cachePolicy

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
  timeoutInterval:timeInterval]
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest
   delegate:self];
```

And use:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
   return nil;
}
```